# Commutator of annichilation and creation operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator

Let $\phi$ be a real scalar field and $\psi$ a complex scalar field. Therefore, we can expand $\phi$ in terms of $a_{\boldsymbol{p}}, a^\dagger_{\boldsymbol{p}}$ and $\psi$ in terms of $b_{\boldsymbol{p}}, b^\dagger_{\boldsymbol{p}}, c_{\boldsymbol{p}}, c^\dagger_{\boldsymbol{p}}$.

Is it true that
\begin{equation}
\left[b_{\boldsymbol{q}}, a^\dagger_{\boldsymbol{p}}\right] = 0?
\end{equation}

I know the usual commutation relations, but I've only seen them related to fields of the same type. I was wondering if such relations exist also if we consider two different types of fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true.  Boson creation operators only have non-zero commutators with annihilation operators of the same type, and Fermion creation operators only have non-zero anticommutators with Fermion annihilation operators of the same type, and they commute with all Boson operators.